# Updating the model instance before it is saved in Database in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I am very new to loopback, and I want to update a particular model instance before creating data into the database.

I have read about Operational hooks, Remote hooks. I have Operational confusion hooks for All models, and remote hooks are for remote methods.

I have created one remote method only and before that remote method is called. I want to add some additional values to the object

How can edit that model instance for that model?

Comment: Hello Vikas, please post the code showing what you have tried out so far. It's difficult to offer a concrete advice when the question is so generic.

Comment: This is totally doable using a beforeRemote hook. But, we can't really delve deeper without any code snippets. Anyway this article may help you: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/applying-custom-logic-in-phases-using-remote-hooks-in-loopback/